# AutoIt scripts start failing on latest Selenium version 2.43

Tags: c#, selenium, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have a simple AutoIt script to upload an image file from an OS dialog. It was working on [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) 2.42 and [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) 31 in [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio). But I did the upgrade of Selenium to 2.43 as Firefox upgrades to 32 version.

Scripts started failing, and I got HTTP request timeout exceptions as the OS browse dialog opened up.

Am I alone in facing this issue with the latest Selenium version?

How do I handle OS dialogs with Selenium in a better way?

Comment: Care to share the stack trace? So little information here.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at

Answer (score 0):

I got that AutoIt script working by catching the httprequest timeout exception and continuing the test. The test runs slower, but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Javascript code to click on browse.

```
browse = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", browse);
```